# Django Send Form By Authenticated User

Tags: django

i stuck when trying to send data or save data with django form by user it self (logged).

When i test why form "From" user must be selectable not automatic selected by user it self.

```
class ValidationCreate(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = About
        fields = '__all__'
```

```
def upload(request):
    upload = ValidationCreate()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        upload = ValidationCreate(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if upload.is_valid():
            upload.save()
            return redirect('validation')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("""your form is wrong, reload on <a href = "{% url 'validation' %}">reload</a>""")

    else:
        return render(request, 'upload_form.html', {'about_form': upload})
```

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouHOc.png)

Comment: From user you can assign from request.user and exclude the field from form

Comment: @bmons can u give the sample please

Comment: upload.instance.user = request.user try it out

Comment: wich one i must excluded ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way you can assign the request.user

```
if upload.is_valid():
    instance = upload.save(commit=False)
    instance.profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user) # you can change the user if field name is different
    instance.save()
    return redirect('validation')
else:
```

in forms

```
fields = ['field_1', 'field_2',] # except user field
```

Comment: nothing change :(
data not saved into user account. I customized for user model, name app is Account and name for model is Profile

Comment: In your form you mention the fields which are required except the user, what is the field name give for user field?

Comment: profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)